# In ASP.NET MVC 5 Application, how to force the user to login if he tries to access secure page without login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

As per the application design, we don't need to maintain Users/Roles information inside our database.

I enter my Employee ID, and I select ***RATES_AMAR_ANALYST*** from the profile dropdown list.

As I selected RATES_AMAR_ANALYST from profile dropdown list, my role is ANALYST.

I am using FormsAuthentication to impliment login, logout functionality.

Below is the code written in LogOff functionality.

```
public ActionResult LogOff(string returnUrl = "")
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

I have written **AuthorizeAttribute** for some business requirement. Hence, registered the same in **FilterConfig.cs** file as shown below.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new SOCOAuthorizeAttribute(string.Empty));
}
```

I have written the following setting in Web.config file to enable forms Authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2" slidingExpiration="true" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" protection="All"></forms>
</authentication>
```

To validate my code, I am trying to access Dashboard URL without login. I am getting below error. But, I want the page to be redirected to Login page instead.

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me how to get my work done!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Sounds like `pnlUser` is `null` in the view.  What is that object and where do you expect it to be set?

Comment: @David: pnlUser is available if user can login properly.

Comment: Well, it would appear you're trying to access an object which isn't set.  The linked duplicate contains helpful information about what that means and how to address it.  You need to either correct why the object isn't being set, or check for null before trying to use it.